# Emit detailed signal in Vala

Tags: vala

I have the following original C code:

```
static guint event_signal_id;

struct _MatrixClientIface {
    void (*event)(MatrixClient *client, const gchar *room_id, const JsonNode *raw_event, MatrixEvent *event);
}

static void
matrix_client_default_init(MatrixClientIface *iface)
{
    event_signal_id = g_signal_new("event",
                                   MATRIX_TYPE_CLIENT,
                                   G_SIGNAL_RUN_LAST | G_SIGNAL_DETAILED,
                                   G_STRUCT_OFFSET(MatrixClientIface, event),
                                   NULL, NULL, _matrix_marshal_VOID__STRING_BOXED_OBJECT,
                                   G_TYPE_NONE, 3,
                                   G_TYPE_STRING,
                                   JSON_TYPE_NODE,
                                   MATRIX_TYPE_EVENT);
}

void
matrix_client_incoming_event(MatrixClient *client,
                             const gchar *room_id,
                             const JsonNode *raw_event,
                             MatrixEvent *event)
{
    GQuark equark;

    equark = g_type_qname(G_TYPE_FROM_INSTANCE(event));

    g_signal_emit(client,
                  event_signal_id, equark,
                  room_id, raw_event, event);
}
```

Now I want to transform this to Vala; however, I cannot find a tutorial about *emitting* signals (defining them appears in tutorials many times). I found `GLib.Signal.emit()` in the docs, but there is no example there on how to get a `GLib.Signal` object.

My current interface looks like this:

```
namespace Matrix {
public interface Client : GLib.Object {
    public virtual signal void
    @event(string? room_id, Json.Node raw_event, Matrix.Event matrix_event)
    {
        Quark equark = @event.get_type().qname();

        @event.emit(room_id, raw_event, matrix_event);
    }
}
```

This obviously doesn’t work. The questions are:

- Am I defining the emitter as I should, at all?
- If so, how do I actually emit the `event` signal with `equark` as a detail?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I cannot find a tutorial about emitting signals (defining them appears in tutorials many times).

I suspect that you actually have, but missed the significance because emitting signals is so easy.  For example, see [the Signals section of the Vala Tutorial](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala/Tutorial#Signals); emitting is shown (`t1.sig_1(5);`).

> I found GLib.Signal.emit() in the docs, but there is no example there on how to get a GLib.Signal object.

`GLib.Signal.emit` is the low-level way of emitting signals, and there is basically no reason to ever use it from Vala.

Note that the first argument to `emit` is a pointer.  There are few exceptions (most notably libxml), but for the most part if you ever encounter a pointer in Vala, you're doing something wrong.  For the most part that also holds true for quarks; virtually everything you would use quarks for has syntax support in Vala.

> Am I defining the emitter as I should, at all?

Nope.  For starters, get rid of the method body and the "virtual".

> If so, how do I actually emit the event signal with equark as a detail?

All you need is something like this:

```
namespace Matrix {
  public class Client : GLib.Object {
    [Signal (detailed = true)]
    public signal void @event (string? room_id, Json.Node raw_event, Matrix.Event evt);
  }
```

To emit it, you can do something like:

```
client.@event[evt.get_type().name()](room_id, raw_event, evt);
```

To connect:

```
client.@event[evt.get_type().name()].connect((room_id, raw_event, evt) => {
    // Signal with a matching detail received
  });
client.@event.connect((room_id, raw_event, evt) => {
    // Signal received with *any* value for the detail
  });
```